# Database Schema for non-structured XML

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following XML:

```
<fooObjects>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>something</name>
    <randomProperty>
        <subRandomProperty>5</subRandomProperty>
    </randomProperty>
    <anotherRandomProperty>1234</anotherRandomProperty>
    ...
</fooObjects>
<barObjects>
    <id>1</id>
    <url>elsething</url>
    <randomProperty>
        <subRandomPropertyX>28</subRandomProperty>
        <subRandomPropertyY>15</subRandomProperty>
    </randomProperty>
    ...
</barObjects>
```

That is, there are two type of entities (`foo`s and `bar`s) that follow a basic structure (id & name for foo, id & url for bar), and then there's a bunch of random properties which can have sub-nodes.

I want to create a MySQL schema to store this kind of data. I think I would need the following tables:

`foo: id [int], name [string]`,

`bar: id [int], url [string]`,

`node: id [int], name [string], value [string], parent_id [int, foreign key referencing node(id)]`.

Where `node` is a vertical key-value table that references to itself, so that nesting is not a problem.

My question has to do with how to link the `foo` and `bar` tables to a `node`. This relation is one-to-many (one `foo` can have many `nodes`) so in theory I should use a `foo_id` in the `node` table (same for `bar`). But this looks weird to me because there can't be a `node` that belongs to both a `foo` and a `bar`. Moreover, there can't be a `node` that has a `parent` and belongs to a `foo` or a `bar` at the same time. That is, those three properties are somehow excluding.

Another option would be to create two more tables:

`node_foo_rel: id [int], id_node [int], id_foo [int]`,

`node_bar_rel: id [int], id_node [int], id_bar [int]`.

This looks cleaner to me, though you have the exact same problem and this is the schema usually used for many-to-many.

What is the standard way of doing this?